# Objective-c: Get file creation date & file modification date/times to the millisecond or nanosecond

Tags: ios, objective-c, creation

the following method just to the second.

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/Raven/Downloads/1.png";
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
NSDate *result = [fileAttribs objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]; //or NSFileModificationDate
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: i dont think the OS stores that kind of precision information, if you create the files yourself, you can store the time more accurately maybe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543563/does-file-attribute-contain-millisecond-objective-c